# How to update global variable in promise and return to use in other components

Tags: angular, typescript, global-variables, es6-promise, angular-promise

The problem is that I have a user name that I want to display, but cannot get the data outside a promise..

I have made a user.service.ts and included that in app.module.ts as a provider. Then in app.component.ts I set user to be equal to the returned data, but it is not working. Why is it not possible to update a global variable within a promise like so?

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthGuardService } from './auth-guard.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

public user: string;

constructor(private authService: AuthGuardService) {

  this.authService.getAuthStatus().then(data => {
    console.log(data.username)
    this.user = data.username;
    return this.user;
  });
 }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd, Route  } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuardService } from './services/auth-guard.service';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie';
import { Window } from 'selenium-webdriver';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
title = 'Fordringsadministration';

private previousUrl: string = undefined;
private currentUrl: string = undefined;
public user: string;

   constructor(
     private router: Router,
     public userService: UserService,
     private cookie: CookieService
  ) {

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.userService.user;
    console.log(this.user)
  }
}
```

Expected result should be sti-admin - which is the current logged in user. But I get undefined?? So this.user is undefined..

Answer (score 2):

`getAuthStatus()` is an async process. So by the mean time, the piece within AppComponent’s `ngOnInit` runs, the user might not have been set yet.

You can verify this by placing debug points within the success handler of the promise and within `ngOnInit`. To achieve your requirement you could have a method in userService as `getUser()` which returns a promise (basically enclosing the logic which is there in the constructor of the `UserService`).

This could be handled in your AppComponent. Moreover, you can cache this and modify the logic accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an observable and fire an event so that the component can listen to it and resolve the username

In the service

```
private _onUserName: Subject<string> = new Subject();
onUserName: Observable<string> = this._onUserName.asObservable();

constructor(private authService: AuthGuardService) {

  this.authService.getAuthStatus().then(data => {
    console.log(data.username)
    this.user = data.username; 
    this._onUserName.next() //fire the event
  });
}
```

And in the component subscribe to it

```
  ngOnInit() {
     this.userService.onUserName.subscribe(item => { 
        console.log(this.userService.user)
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - just had to return it as a promise. This way I can just write this.user in all components.